# Web application - Sudden slowness

Tags: oracle, performance, apache, tomcat, java-7

We are maintaining a web application which is built using below software,

1. Web server - Apache HTTPD
2. App server - Apache Tomcat 7
3. JDK - JDK 1.7
4. Server - RHEL
5. Database - Oracle

It was working fine till last week, however suddenly two days back it started causing performance issues. It is accessed by 400 employees within a private network. The slowness is seen across the application. Below are some actions we have taken so far,

1) Check if the linux server is responding slow (%CPU, %MEM).
2) Check if the tomcat instance is causing the issue like out of memory error, deadlocks, GC etc.
3) Check if there are long running queries, DB locks etc.

But everything looks normal and we are out of clue. Can someone suggest options and ways to identify the problem?

Update : We had a apache web server migrated to 2.4 two months back.

Comment: This is probably too broad a question for this sort of forum.  I'm a database guy so I'd start with the database.  Is statspack installed?  Are you licensed to use the AWR?  I'd take an AWR/ statspack report from a representative hour last week and another from the same period today and compare them.  Are the wait events different?  Are the top SQL statements different?  Or are they the same SQL statements just taking longer?  Or being executed more often?

Comment: Are you sure it is only this application - other things on the server run as normal (even general shell activity, listing directories), and it isn't a slowdown in the network (which could potentially be a routing change, firewall/IDS problem, proxy), etc.?

Comment: Justin, Yes, i am able to take the AWR report. In fact, i have the AWR report for today. But i haven't taken the AWR report for last week. I would definitely ask the DBA to pull the AWR report and check further. Please help provide some details on what to compare in both reports.

Comment: Alex, Yes, everything else on the servers run normal. Directory listing and execution of shell scripts are working as expected.

Comment: From the database perspective check if all the indexes are in Valid status or not, check ASH, AWR reports and application logs. As a last resort just bounce your database and application (not a cool idea but might work)

Comment: This is **way** too broad to answer here, there are is a massive list of things you need to check and in most cases you're going to need the same metrics from when the system was running properly. But I will throw you a bone - try disabling bind peeking on the database.